# DraftJS - Make first N character of the editor static

Tags: draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg, draft-js-plugins

If there a way to make the first N characters of the Editor to be static.
I tried using a decorator, but when you select all characters and press delete, it deletes the entire data.